# How to obtain DataFrame from the database table retrived with JDBC cut by the multiple date ranges with one date range per row in another DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have the DataFrame with the event start time:

```
val dailySummariesDfVisualize =
      dailySummariesDf
    .orderBy("event_time").registerTempTable("raw")    

val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from raw")
df.show()

+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
|          event_type|         event_time|event_payload|coffee_machine_id|digital_twin_id|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
|Large_Cup_Button_...|2021-03-24 07:06:34|         null|       NP20100005|     NP20100005|
|Large_Cup_Button_...|2021-03-24 07:07:41|         null|       NP20100005|     NP20100005|
```

I'd like each `event_time` row would be the start of the time range and `event_time+1 minute` would be the end of the time range, and there would be as many time ranges as there are rows in the DataFrame above. I'd like to make a query and extact to the new DataFrame from another table only the items between the start and the end of each time range. How can I do that? Is join here the only option, or neted query can be useful? Or may be only foreach on DataFrame can be helpful there?

Comment: Probably a window function, but can you specify the output you expect? Because the description is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy it was fount that procuding the where clause from relatively small dataset to extract the only needed data from the greated dataset works fine for my case, I'll add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve that with producing the where clause in scala from the DataFrame Rows, which are not so numerous compared to the data from whom I do the extraction query:

```
var collectedString = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()

for (row <- dailySummariesDfVisualize.collectAsList())
  {
      println(row(1))
      val start = row(1)
      val end = row(5)
      val timeSelection = s" time > ' ${start}' and  time < '${end}'"
      collectedString+=timeSelection    
  }

val whereClause = collectedString.mkString(" or ")
println(whereClause)

val dailySensorData =
      getDFFromJdbcSource(SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate(), 
      s"SELECT *  FROM values WHERE "+whereClause+" limit 1000000")
       .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)    

dailySensorData.show(400, false)
```

It does the output what I was actually needed with acceptable performance.

The formatted whereClause output is something like:

```
time > ' 2021-03-24 07:06:34.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:08:34.0' or  time > ' 2021-03-24 07:07:41.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:09:41.0' or  time > ' 2021-03-24 07:07:43.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:09:43.0'
```

and so on

So just with adding this where clause to

```
s"SELECT *  FROM values WHERE "+whereClause+" limit 1000000"
```

I was able to extract only needed time ranges from the data in one query the most optimal way.